# c# NodaTime - Read ISO String as EST time

Tags: c#, .net, nodatime

Assume there's a table with a datetime column represented as ISO string. The datetime data is initially represented as NodaTime ZonedDateTime format in EST. and then it's converted to string format as `2021-02-10T02:07:07.000 -05` For example:

```
// datetime data represented as ZonedDateTime
var dateTimeUtc = new DateTime(2021, 2, 10, ,7, 7, 7, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTimeUtc);
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZoneNewYork();

// convert datetime value to ISO string
var IsoString = zonedDateTime.Value.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss;fff +o<HH>", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Now I need to retrieve this value from table and represent it in ZonedDateTime EST format.
If I want to get this value from the this table, I can do something like:

```
var parsePattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss;fff +O<HH>", DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
```

However the returned string is represented as UTC time `2021-02-10T02:07:07 UTC (+00)` which is not accurate (the actual saved value is EST).

Is there a way I can read ISO string with a specified time zone using NodaTime?

Comment: You've already accepted an answer, but an important aspect of this is that you *don't have a time zone*. You actually have a time zone offset. So you should (IMO) be parsing this as an `OffsetDateTime` instead, because that's what your textual data represents.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way I can read ISO string with a specified time zone using
> NodaTime?

Changing format of `ZonedDateTime` Iso string representation, and preserving that format for both conversion operations should help.

Change `"yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss;fff +O<HH>"` to `ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso.PatternText` like:

```
var dateTimeUtc = new DateTime(2021, 2, 10, 7, 7, 7, DateTimeKind.Utc);
var instant = Instant.FromDateTimeUtc(dateTimeUtc);

DateTimeZone ny = DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb["America/New_York"];
var zonedDateTime = instant.InZone(ny);

// convert datetime value to ISO string


var IsoString = zonedDateTime.ToString(ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso.PatternText,
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);


//parse iso string, like "2021-02-10T02:07:07 America/New_York (-05)"

var parsePattern = ZonedDateTimePattern.CreateWithInvariantCulture(
                      ZonedDateTimePattern.GeneralFormatOnlyIso.PatternText, 
                      DateTimeZoneProviders.Tzdb);
var date2 = parsePattern.Parse("2021-02-10T02:07:07 America/New_York (-05)").Value;
```